# I am getting error like "Assignment to read only property" in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

If VIN is an text field this code works for me to Hiding keyboard without breaking UITextField functionality..

```
UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
VIN.inputView = dummyView;
```

But in another case i need to do same thing for UIVIEW.. it is possible to do for UIView ?

```
UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
VIN.inputView = dummyView;
```

In this case VIN Is an UIView.. i am getting error like "Assignment to read only property".

Comment: input View is only the property of textview that can be assigned. You should check the docs to read more about usage of methods and properties if you arent sure about them

Comment: some helpful information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html

Answer (score 1):

`UITextfield` has `inputview`. Default inputview is keyboard. uiview has not input view that you can set so you can't assign input view to `UIView`.

And for hiding keyboard you should call `resignFirstresponder` like,

```
 [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

This will hide keyboard and when you click textfield it will show keyboard again so you should do like this.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **hide or disable keyboard for particular textfield** , you can use following textfield delegate

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Here You can do additional code or task instead of writing with keyboard

    if (textField == YourTextField)
    {
       return NO;//Keyboar Wont appear for textfield
    }

    return YES;
}
```